# WPF / Silverlight - selected row style on DataGrid

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, datagrid

What is the best way to get a row-by-row selection feel to a DataGrid in Silverlight rather than a selected row and an active cell? For my current application I just don't need the UI effect of an active cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your DataGrid's `SelectionUnit` property to `FullRow`. I know it works with WPF although I am not sure if Silverlight syntax is the same or not

Comment: I can see this is a valid property according to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectionunit.aspx but when I try to get to the property from Intellisense - no luck. It is not there. Thoughts?

Comment: I've never worked with Silverlight before, just WPF. Perhaps it is a property that doesn't exist in Silverlight? I know the WPF DataGrid control was only recently added with .Net Framework 4.0. An alternative might be to just style the ActiveCell the same as the SelectedRow

Comment: I think you are right. Might have to ask some friends or come back here and find out what the Silverlight equivalent is. +1

Comment: On the MSDN page, you can see this property is only in .NET 4 (WPF) and not Silverlight bec there is no "Other Versions" dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the visual effect through stying by removing the "FocusVisual" in the CellStyle.  The whole row will still be highlighted, but the individual cell that was clicked will not look any different from the other cells in the row.

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
x:Class="SO_DataGridVertical.MainPage"
Width="640" Height="480">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="sdk:DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridCell">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CurrentStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Regular"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Current">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                    -->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Invalid">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="InvalidVisualElement"/>
                                        <!--<ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                        -->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InteractionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Display"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Editing"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <!--<Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual" Fill="#66FFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>-->
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="InvalidVisualElement" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stroke="#FFDC000C" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="RightGridLine" Loaded="RightGridLine_Loaded"  Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
    <sdk:DataGrid    ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}" />
</Grid>
```